# C++ - SDL: For loop and strings

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, sdl

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if (text.at(i) != '$')
        {
            currentLine += text.substr(i, 1);
            // replacing it with currentLine="blabla"; still gives errors
        }
        else
        {
            // currentLine = "blabla"; -- no errors
            drawText(currentLine, x, y + lineID * 10);
            lineID++;
            currentLine = "";
        }
    }
```

The function is to draw a string multi-line, $ stands for break line.

Unless currentLine is set right before drawing, I receive an error that my screen.format.palette.ncolors and colors cannot be evaluated.

Let's assume drawText function works right. Then what causes this error? Nothing ever changes currentLine apart from this code.

EDIT:

**currentLine (which is an std::string) appears to be empty. currentLine+" " however returns the proper string plus the space.** What could cause it?

EDIT #2:

Fixed. Somehow... Magic.

Comment: `substr()` is really an overkill here. Just say `currentLine += text[i];` But the code is fine, bug is elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you. Too bad it does not fix my problem. :\

Comment: Why should we assume that `drawText` works right?

Comment: use if (text[i] != '$') instead of what you have there

Comment: also, can you post your drawText function?

Comment: "screen.format.palette.ncolors and colors cannot be evaluated" - this doesnt look like something caused by a little bit of string manipulation. Have you tried dumping the strings you are processing to stdout or a text file to see if you get what you expect?

Comment: `currentLine` is `std::string`, is it?

Comment: drawText works, I have tested it. drawText("hello"); and a="hello"; drawText(a); would both work. currentLine is std::string. @mathematician1975, doing it right now.

Comment: Are you checking the value of `currentLine` before passing it to `drawText()`? Does `drawText()` handle empty strings, very long strings and strings containing unprintable characters sensibly?

Comment: @Aaron That test doesn't mean anything. How does it handle empty strings? Why not post `drawText` so we can see how it uses `currentLine`?

Comment: Indeed I was an idiot and drawString cannot handle empty strings. Very sorry about my stubborness. HOWEVER. printf(currentLine) would do nothing. printf(currentLine+" ") would output the right string plus the space. drawText(currentLine) gives an error. drawText(currentLine+" ") works. drawText(currentLine+"") does not work either. currentLine alone is empty? Why would that happen?

Comment: @Aaron Yet you still aren't showing us what is inside `drawText`... And what does "does not work" mean? One second, I'll grab my crystal ball...

Comment: @StackUnderflow My bad, that is how I used it. It would give an error otherwise. printf(currentLine.c_str()) gives me an empty string, while printf(currentLine.c_str() + " ") gives me "asd ", where asd is what currentLine is supposed to be.

Comment: "Does not work" means that I get an error because drawText tries to handle an empty string. There is no drawText anymore though. I have the currentLine string and the printf functions. currentLine alone is empty, currentLine+" " is currentLine and a space (properly).